# VBA: Efficient way of extracting href from TD's innerhtml in HTML Table

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am extracting href from TD's innerHTML which resides in an HTML Table.

URL used:
`http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/mutualfunds/mfinfo/portfolio_holdings/MMO029`

There's table by class `tblporhd` from which I am fetching data. I am extracting from site using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` object which I am loading in an `HTMLDocument` and it is working fine. My doubt is in the method I am employing to extract href from one of the cell (TD) in a table. I am passing `innerHTML` to `RegExp` based UDF like below.

`strGetURL(objCell.innerHTML)`

Function is as below (Working):

```
Private Function strGetURL(strInput As String) As String
Dim RgEx As Object: Set RgEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim objMatches As Object
With RgEx
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "href=(["" '])(.*?)\1"
End With

Set objMatches = RgEx.Execute(strInput)
If objMatches.Count <> 0 Then
    strGetURL = Replace(objMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(1), "about:/", "http://www.moneycontrol.com/")
Else
End If

End Function
```

**Query:**

While I have the code working, is there any method of getting the same result by using some default feature / syntax or better way which is already available to deal with in HTMLDocument Table Cell?

I have searched internet but couldn't find any relevant code so posting a new question. Let me know if any additional information is required.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I could understand the requirement. However, let me tell you straight what I could surmise: You expect to have all the data from a table under `tblporhd` class name out of the above mentioned webpage using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` request and you want to have `href`'s as well, right?

Comment: @Shahin Yes. I already have a working solution to extract the full table. The standard portions are taken care of using `innerText`. In this particular table, there are cells which have hyperlinks (href) which point to individual stock e.g. `http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/finance-housing/housingdevelopmentfinancecorporation/HDF`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it will solve the issue. Try now:

```
Sub TableData()
    Const base_url As String = "http://www.moneycontrol.com"
    Dim HTTP As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim posts As Object, elem As Object, trow As Object

    With HTTP
        .Open "GET", "http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/mutualfunds/mfinfo/portfolio_holdings/MMO029", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set posts = html.getElementsByClassName("tblporhd")(0)

    For Each elem In posts.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each trow In elem.getElementsByTagName("td")
            With trow.getElementsByTagName("a")
                If .Length Then Cells(z + 1, 1) = base_url & Split(.Item(0).href, "about:")(1)
            End With
            y = y + 1: Cells(r + 1, y + 1) = trow.innerText
        Next trow
        y = 0
        r = r + 1
        z = z + 1
    Next elem
End Sub
```

Comment: Like the one you gave me yesterday while dealing with harcoded number to parse some json data.

Answer (score 0):

Well your node variable is `objCell` and its definition is not given.  For most (all?) HTML nodes there will be an `innerhtml` property but why not cast to a variable of type `MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement` and then use the anchor's `href` property?